Processing and loading large sets of data into Postgres with Python
I am migrating data from Microsoft Access Database (.mdb) into a Postgres Database. The dataset is very large and I need to process the data before loading it into the database(Postgres).
My approch seems to be very slow and I need some help making it faster.
I've created an insert method which when called establishes a connection to the Postgres Database first and then executes the insert query before it closes the connection.
So far I've tried the following approaches:
Single Insert: Where I process a single row of data and insert it. This approach was slow because anytime the insert method is called, a connection needs to be established before the insertion is done and then the connection is closed. This happens for every single row, making it slow.
Then I tried Bulk Insert: Where I process all the columns before calling the insert method. I created a bulk insert method for this approach using pandas and SQLAlchemy. This method however takes a very long time too because even though the connection is established only ones, all the data must be processed first before the insertion happens.
Now I'm thinking the best approach will be to use Batching: Where I process a chunk of the data, insert and then go back to process the rest and insert.
I realized combining multithreading with Batching can help to improve the speed significantly.
Please I need suggestions on which approach will be best. Even if it is different from the one I have mentioned.

Export each table to CSV, import each CSV into PostgreSQL using COPY. 1TB per hour is doable. Row by row is by far the slowest option

Frank Heikens, I will try this approach and get back to you. Thank you.

Check the manual about using copy: https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/copy.html

Works like magic. Thank you so much.

Maybe for the single insert approach, you could use connection pooling to reuse the connections instead of setting them up and tearing them down each time.
See https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/pooling.html for details
